# Smallest whole number coefficient?

Tags: homework, stoichiometry

What is the smallest whole number coefficent of $\ce {Cr^{2+}}$ when the equation is balanced?
$$\ce {Cr^{2+}_{(aq)} + Al_{(s)} -> Cr_{(s)} + Al^{3+}_{(aq)}}$$

I don't understand, how can this be balanced? And why would 3 be the smallest coefficient?

Comment: Currently, the charges are not balanced. You need to balance the charges to have a balanced equation.

Comment: You need to balance the reaction, that's it. But you should know step wise method, because if you use try and error method you might waste your lot of time!

Answer (score 2):

You need to factor in the electrons that are being moved around

Chromium is doing this:
$\ce {Cr^{2+}_{(aq)} + 2 e- ->  Cr_{(s)}}$

Aluminum is doing the reverse of this:

$\ce {Al^{3+}_{(aq)} + 3 e- -> Al_{(s)}}$

Now, like a math equation flip around the aluminum reaction.
And balance out the electrons

$\ce {[Cr^{2+} + 2 e- ->   Cr_{(s)}] \times 3}$

$\ce {[Al_{(s)} -> Al^{3+} + 3 e- ] \times 2}$

---

$\ce {3Cr^{2+} + 6 e- + 2 Al_{(s)} -> 3Cr_{(s)} + 2 Al^{3+} + 6 e-}$

Hope this helps